# ¿Cuando llamo a una clase desde un modulo a quien estoy llamando? Python

Tags: python, clase, objeto, método

Pregunta de teoría.

Cuando quiero convertir la información de un archivo .csv en un diccionario utilizo el modulo csv

```
import csv

file = open("archivo.csv", "r")
Diccionario = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter='  ')
```

Si yo abro el modulo csv de python veo que DictReader es una clase no una función.

**Preguntas:**

- Realmente como funciona ese proceso?
- si "Diccionario" es un objeto de la clase "DictReader" como se ejecutó automáticamente el proceso de devolver un diccionario si no he accedido a ningún método ( Diccionario.metodo() )?
- Cuando llamo a una clase que pertenece a un modulo exterior se ejecutan todos sus métodos al mismo tiempo? De ser así, si una clase tiene 100 métodos y todos devuelven algo obtendría entonces 100 resultado?
- las clases retornan algo como lo hace una función (return)?

Gracias.
Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Realmente como funciona ese proceso?

Verás cuando se crea un objeto en Python, siempre se llama el método [`__new__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__). Este método es el encargado de hacer ese *retorno automático*, sin haber llamado a un método del objeto.

Por otro lado, el método [`__init__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) es el que se encarga de definir el constructor predeterminado de la clase, `__init__()` de alguna manera a llama a `__new__()` para generar esa nueva instancia de la clase.

> las clases retornan algo como lo hace una función (return)?

**Las clases no** retornan nada. Sin embargo, cuando se crea un objeto en base a una clase siempre se llama el constructor predeterminado. Este es la función que retorna el valor que se le asigna a una variable para que sea un objeto.

La diferencia que existen entre los constructores y los otros métodos de la clase, es que el constructor es el método que se llama al mismo momento de instanciar la clase. Justo cuando se inicializa un objeto, se ejecuta el constructor.

```
class Foo:
    def __new__(self):
        return "Bar"

baz = Foo()
print(baz)
```

Este fragmento de código muestra *Bar* por consola, si lo notas **nunca se llamó al método `__new__()`.** Este método se ejecuto apenas se inicializó el objeto, a `baz` se le asignó su valor de retorno.

El método `__init__()` va de la mano con el método `__new__()`:

*Del [modelo de datos](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) en la documentación:*

> `object.__init__(self[, ...])`
> Called after the instance has been created (by **new**()), but before it is returned to the caller. The arguments are those passed to the class constructor expression.

A rasgos abstractos, `__init__()` es el constructor de la clase y este trabaja con `__new__()` para devolver un objeto. Como digo, ambos métodos se ejecutan al instanciar la clase con un objeto, son los primeros métodos de la clase que se ejecutan.

Por eso mismo da una sensación de que a `Diccionario` se le está asignando el retorno de una función, es lo que realmente está pasando, se le está asignando el valor retornado por `__new__()` que es un objeto que se construye en base a `__init__()`.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Primero, la llamada con el csv. El truco es que importaste el módulo completo, no solo una de las definiciones del módulo. También es posible hacerlo así:

```
from csv import DictReader
Diccionario = DictReader(file, delimiter='  ')
```

Segunda pregunta. Lo que tienes en Diccionario es una *instancia* que fue creada al llamar al constructor de DictReader. En realidad no has llamado a ningún método de la instance.... *salvo* lo que se esté llamando dentro del constructor (eso, siguiendo la premisa que colocaste: *...veo que DictReader es una clase no una función*).

Tercera pregunta: No. Se llaman en la medida en la que hay llamadas en el constructor o que tú las vayas llamando en el código.

El constructor devuelve una instancia de la clase. Otros métodos de una clase se comportan exactmante igual a una función, pueden devolver algo como puede ser que no devuelvan nada.

Comment: Siguiendo lo que me explicas, he importado solo la clase DictReader, esta contiene tres métodos especiales: "__init__"," __iter__"(No conozco ese método)  "__next__" (tampoco lo conozco) y  "fieldnames()" (un metodo declarado dos veces cada uno con un decorador diferente). Esos 3 métodos especiales se ejecutan si o si cuando se crea la instancia de clase?

Comment: No sabría... Si se están llamando dentro del constructor, entonces si. Si no, pues no.

Comment: Cual seria el constructor? en el  curso que vi dicen que es el "init", pero el resto de internet dice que no lo es xD. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: El contructor en python es una función que se llama `__init__` en una clase.... y si lo que dice internet es lo contrario, pues les tengo malas noticias: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__... dicha función (en todo caso) es llamada _automagicamente_ al crear la instancia... como cuando haces `Diccionaro = DictReader(blahblah)`